# Running Windows executables in Raspbian?

Tags: pi-3, software-installation, windows, raspbian-stretch

I found an interest in [Unity](https://unity3d.com/) programming a few days ago and decided to try it out on linux, specifically, Raspbian Stretch. My question here has to do with the running of .exe files on Raspbian so I can open the Unity editor.

Fail. I tried many things:

- Downloaded an experimental Unity version for linux from the website ([linux releases and notes](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/)), but the installer wouldn't run; the terminal wouldn't even start up! (The installer was supposed to open in terminal)
- Tried getting the Windows version from the Unity website. Attempted to run it. Fail. Tried it with [dosbox](https://www.dosbox.com/), but it said that it couldn't run the file (displayed nothing more).
- Looked all over [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), and [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) but didn't find anything relevant. Many answers to questions like this were for other operating systems that didn't work for me or contained examples of successful runs of many Windows executables with Wine, but when I tried `wine examplefile.exe` on my Unity installer, Wine outputted this:

> Warning: memory above 0x80000000 doesn't seem to be accessible.
>
> Wine requires a 3G/1G user/kernel memory split to work properly.
>
> wine: failed to map the shared user data: c0000018

I have no idea what this means...

- Found a windows emulator called [Exagear](https://eltechs.com/product/exagear-desktop/) but it's paid, so I'm only willing to use this as a last resort. It might not even work. One thing I found told me to run Exagear with `exagear` from the command prompt but that would require an insertion of a license key. Then to test Exagear's functionality I could have tried doing `arch`. I don't think this would work though. An opinion on the functionality of Exagear would be nice.
- Another stack exchange post suggested using the Windows emulator qemu, but it's a rather big file, and that Super User question didn't help. Not only would I take up tons of space on my SD, I would also have to wait half an hour for the download time and another fifteen minutes for removal of qemu if it doesn't work!

So how can I get *any* Windows file to run on Raspbian? I'm looking for a solution that works with a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Stretch; many potential solutions were for outdated systems: Raspberry Pi 2, Raspbian Wheezy, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can with Exagear and wine. But it will be pretty slow, so it's not really worth it. Even a native client would be slow, Raspi (especially when it comes to 3D stuff) is slower than the cheapest phone you can buy today.